# Problems reading XML InputStream in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

In my main activity I have this call:

```
InputStream stream = http_conn.getInputStream();
            ParseXML.Login(stream);
```

I know the input stream is working as I can create a buffered reader, creating a string that I can send to the UI. The issue is this reports the entire XML document that is being returned to me.

Within my ParseXML class Login method, I have the following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stream);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

So far so good, I think? I am new to using parsers, but basically the layout of my XML document is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.xxx.com/asmx">TOKEN HERE</string>
```

I have seen examples in which you can retrieve various items from deeper with an XML file, as per the example here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

I'm not only new to XML parsers but new to java as well, I just can't figure out how to pull that string out of the XML document!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I'm understanding but if you want to get only TOKEN HERE try doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent()